# Description Resource Path Location Type error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android

I found several answers in this powerful stackoverflow, but so far no idea why it still does not work. I have tried: update sdk, relocate eclipse and workspace to be under the same root repository, and even the project->properties->android->add, which is empty. In order to show what I have there, I had two screenshots below. The problem is

```
Description Resource Path Location Type error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.styles.xml
Description Resource Path Location Type error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.styles.xml
Description Resource Path Location Type error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.styles.xml
```

[image: properties of project shows that it is empty]

[image: SDK manager with the only checked items kept in the picture]

Thanks

Comment: Finally got this problem solved. 1, like suraj said, create a new project, it gives a appcombat in workspace 2, a new problem shows up, non 'gen' and non existing 'appcombat.jar', so clean and rebuild appcombat project, making 'gen' back, 3, add library appcombat in the project properties. 4, clean and rebuild project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppCompat` is a library project ans is missing. You need to reference the library project in your android project.

you can do one thing create a demo application in eclipse and make target same as your this application. it will automatic create a `AppCompat` lib. then add this lib to your project.

It will solve your problem.